# Is it possible to get the 3D view from Kinect v2 in Windows 10

Tags: kinect-v2

I want to get access to the 3D view. Please see below the screenshot of 3D view displayed in Kinect Studio:

[image]

Is it possible to access this view? may be by using Microsot API? Or something like Point Cloud data?

Comment: There is both Microsoft official API (Windows 8 and higher) to do it and opensource libfreenect2.

Comment: Also, examples in Kinect 2 SDK consist of many Kinect Studio functionalities, so there may be exact code to get this view. I cannot check it right now from the phone unfortunatelly

Comment: https://kinectforwindows.codeplex.com/ You want to check Depth with color sample (C++ only).

Comment: @R2RT: I am browsing the above link. To run "Depth with Color" sample code, Do I need to install [Kinect for Windows SDK v1.8](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40278) and [Kinect for Windows Developer Toolkit v1.8](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40276)? I already have Kinect Studio and Kinect Drivers installed for Kinect V2. I am on WIndows 10 64 Bit operating system. Can you please confirm it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, seems I've made mistake when I did search for that samples, since these samples are for first Kinect, not Kinect v2. You need Kinect v2 SDK: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44561 Ther eshould be similar sample with Colored Depth inside of it

Comment: @R2RT: I have already installed Kinect V2 (before posting the question). However, I am not able to get the 3D view example code. I can get the color data, depth data, ir data, audio data etc. But I am not able to find out 3D view example code.